# How to get current location in android from google services?

Tags: android

I want to get the current location in a background service from google services.
I know there's the `getLastLocation()` method, but its states on android developer website that it

> Returns the best most recent location currently available. If a
>   location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null will
>   be returned.

So, does that mean that if there is no recent location, it wont use the GPS to get it? if not, is there another way to directly get location?

Answer (score 1):

To getting location you can use **LocationManager** object.

For request for location you can use `requestLocationUpdates` method from `LocationManager` class as is shown in the code below:

```
    //This is the way to get LocationManager instance
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Listener below is used to getting location and to getting information about providers
    final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
    //on line below, is location manager requests for new location
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

You can put code above in some service and get location in every defined time.

But you remember to proper work you neeed permissions below in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: that doesn't answer my question, which was if getLastLocation() method can't find a location, will it try to get location or not?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, if there is no location it will not try to get it until you request it. Konrad is already pointing on the right direction but Google Dev has a complete [step-by-step guide](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) using the latest APIs.

Comment: so do you know how to request it using google api? or do you mean that if there's no recent location then i have to request it using location manager?

Comment: LocationManager used to be the way to do that. Now you use LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
You can start reading from here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#location-request